# why do i keep getting an error message whenever i git push

Tags: git, git-push

when ever i git push it usually give this error message 'The requested URL returned error: 403'

i am expected to get something like this'Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 212 bytes | 212.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)'

but got this 'The requested URL returned error: 403'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.